# Python Checking internet connection with loop

Tags: python, loops, web

I  tried to write a simple script, which keep iterating if there is no internet connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request, time;

while True:
    try:
        file = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com');
        print('Connect');
        break;

    except urllib.error.URLError:
        print('No connect');
        time.sleep(3);
```

It should keep iterating while the internet is disconnected. But when I connect to the web, the break expression doesn't trigger. The important thing is that I want my script  breaking loop if there is internet connection, without restarting script.

Comment: Your code is running fine on my machine. Could you tell exactly what is happening when you connect ? Update the environment in which you are working as well. It is remote possibility but can happen that terminal does not have access to internet due to certain proxy settings (have seen it in ubuntu)

Comment: I use fedora, and when I launch script from terminal typing 'python script.py' whith connecting internet, the break statement is triggered. But, when I disconnect from internet and than launch script, after I connect to the web again simultaneously whith launching script, the break statement doesnt work and terminal printing the 'No connect' string in looping.

Comment: Just a style note: in python semicolon is not required in the end of the statement.

Comment: It's my habit from javascript:)

Comment: I cannot think of anything. It looks like a system specific problem. I would have tried using 'http://74.125.228.100'. It is the ip address of google.com and avoids dns lookup

Comment: or actually you could use `8.8.8.8` or `4.4.4.4` which are google's open dns. And BTW, you should send an [ICMP ping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping), which is lighter for your network and your CPU.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your help. I performed my task via simple ping command from terminal, using os.system and without exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this :

```
import requests,time

    def check():
        try:
            requests.get('https://www.google.com/').status_code
            print('online')
            time.sleep(5)
            check_again()
        except:
            print('offline')
            time.sleep(5)
            
    def check_again():
        try:
            requests.get('https://www.google.com/').status_code
            print('online')
            time.sleep(5)
            check()
        except:
            print('offline')
            time.sleep(5)
            check()
    check()
```